# Change wordpress theme file

Tags: wordpress, caching, themes

I tried to change Worpdress theme files. (page.php, style.css)

But changes seem not to affect actual website pages.

I have these plugins installed:

- WooCommerce

- Additional Variation Images Gallery for WooCommerce

- WooCommerce AJAX Products Filter

- XforWooCommerce

Can it be related to some kind of cache?

I tried to clear the cache using the plugin but it didn't help

Comment: Are you sure you are updating the correct theme? Go to Appearance > Themes to see the active theme. You might be also using a child theme. I would also recommend you use a child theme if you are trying to write over a theme you bought so that the changes don't break on updates

Comment: Read the official docs on how to work with child themes : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/